# HTML/CSS3 - Align text issues

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

i'm trying to align text in center position, but i've some problems with the `<h1>` element and i cannot understand why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Termoidraulica</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Berkshire+Swash" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/commons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    <style>
.cover {    
    position: relative;
    width: 95%;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #333;
}
.cover-caption {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;   
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="cover">
        <div class="cover-caption">
            <h1 class="cover-title">TITLE</h1>
            <p class="cover-subtitle">Subtitle</p>
            <button class="cover-btn">SHOP NOW!</button>
        </div>
    </section>    
</body>
</html>
```

On codepen i've paste all my code, if here is too much confused. [LINK](https://codepen.io/Alfaver/pen/LeGQZE?editors=1100)

Thanks in advance

By

Comment: @TemaniAfif Unfortunately i found the the same issue on my IDE. I've only copied and pasted the HTML/CSS code on CodePen.
Without transform i don't know how to center verticaly and horizontaly the <div class="cover-caption">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is coming from the navbar element where you specified a `height:40px`. So you can remove this value to make it auto or add `overflow: hidden` (this will fix the issue of your actual code).

By the way, you have the float element `.navbar-menu` inside the `.navbar` that is making issue as you are not clearing the float correctly. You can also consider adding `<div class="clearfix"></div>` before the section containing the title instead of adding `clearfix` class to the previous container.

Here is the full code :

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #eee;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 40px;
}

.navbar-logo {
  color: #409be8;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.7em 0 0 2.5%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.navbar-menu {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 2.5% 0 0;
}

.navbar-menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-menu-item a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 1em;
  color: #409be8;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
  transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
}

.navbar-menu-item a:hover {
  background-color: #409be8;
  color: #eee;
}

.navbar-menu-icon {
  display: none;
  float: right;
  padding: 1.2em 1.2em 0 0;
}

.navbar-menu-icon span {
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #409be8;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.animate {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

.cover {
  position: relative;
  width: 95%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #333;
}

.cover-caption {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.cover-title {
  font-family: 'Berkshire Swash', cursive;
}
```

```html
<section class="navbar">
  <a href="" class="navbar-logo">Logo</a>
  <a href="" class="navbar-menu-icon">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="navbar-menu animate">
    <li class="navbar-menu-item"><a href="">item 1</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-menu-item"><a href="">item 2</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-menu-item"><a href="">item 3</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-menu-item"><a href="">item 4</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-menu-item"><a href="">item 5</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-menu-item"><a href="">item 6</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-menu-item"><a href="">item 7</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<section class="cover">
  <div class="cover-caption">
    <h1 class="cover-title">TITLE</h1>
    <p class="cover-subtitle">Subtitle</p>
    <button class="cover-btn">SHOP NOW!</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks !! But why the Height of Navbar create this issue?

Comment: @MikeAlFaverFavro you are not clearing the floating element correctly ;)

Comment: Thanks for the code :D
But now i have another problems...between section navbar and cover there is some space, but i can not understand why .. 
i don't have margin, padding or anything else.

(yes, i'm newbie)

Comment: @MikeAlFaverFavro ah no, you have margin of h1 which is collpasing, remove it

Comment: Nice!! Yes,now is all ok :D Many Many thanks dude :D

Answer (score 0):

Your `clear: both` from `.clearfix:after` in the first `<section>` isn't taking effect - I've never tried to clear in an `:after` before and don't know whether it's meant to work, but it clearly isn't working here.

Easist fix in my experimentation was to add `clear: both` to the `<section>` containing the misbehaving `<h1>`.